# Finding next fibonacci number

Tags: php, fibonacci

I need to find a (the next) fibonacci number given a integer N. So let's say I have n = 13 and I need to output the next fibonacci number which is 21 but how do I do this? How can I find the previous number that summed up to form it?

I mean I could easily come up with a for/while loop that returns the fibonacci sequence but how can I find the next number by being given the previous one.

```
<?php

$n = 13;

while($n < 1000) {

    $n = $x + $y; 
    echo($n."<br />"); 
    $x = $y;
    $y = $n;
}
?>
```

Comment: Why not just create a loop that continues one more iteration than it takes to get the inputted sum? This may not be the most efficient way to do this, but it is A way.

Comment: Could it be about the ratio of the two number that go into the term that you are given? The ration of the numbers tends towards 1.618. Is it then fairly easy to work out what the two integers must be? Divide the given term by 1.618 to get an idea of one of the digits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a loop you could store the values in an array that could stop immediately one key after finding the selected number in the previous keys value.

```
function getFib($n) {

   $fib = array($n+1);       // array to num + 1
   $fib[0] = 0; $fib[1] = 1; // set initial array keys
   $i;

   for ($i=2;$i<=$n+1;$i++) {
      $fib[$i] = $fib[$i-1]+$fib[$i-2];
        if ($fib[$i] > $n) { // check if key > num 
            return $fib[$i];
            }
        }
    if ($fib[$i-1] < $n) {   // check if key < num
        return $fib[$i-1] + $n;
    }
    if ($fib[$i] = $n-1) {   // check if key = num
        return $fib[$i-1] + $fib[$i-2];
    } 
    if ($fib[$i-1] = 1) {    // check if num = 1
        return $n + $n;
    }
}

$num = 13;
echo "next fibonacci number = " . getFib($num);
```

*Please note that I haven't tested this out and the code could be optimized, so before downvoting consider this serves only as a concept to the question asked.*

Comment: You're welcome, glad it helped. If you wanted to carry it a step further you could have it identify whether or not the `$num` is a fibonacci number as well. Here's a working example: http://ideone.com/vr5bJH

Comment: Yes, I wrote something similar afterwards. Anyway, I've another quick question. How can I get the first N members of the sequence? So far I've come up to this only: http://pastebin.com/qHvjUzdC

But in this way I output only numbers starting from 3 and I also need 0,1,1 and 2 as of the beginning of the fibonacci series.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Binet's Formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Relation_to_the_golden_ratio):

```
          n          -n
F(n) = phi   - (-phi)
       ---------------
          sqrt(5)
```

where phi is the golden ratio `(( 1 + sqrt(5) ) / 2) ~= 1.61803...`

This lets you determine exactly the n-th term of the sequence.

Comment: How can I possibly implement that in PHP?

Comment: But this cannot help to find Fibonacci number closest to the given number

Comment: @hindmost You could use the formula to find `n` for `F(n) = 13` then use it again to calculate n-1.

Comment: @hindmost: sure you can. start filling in `n` values and use a binary-type search to narrow down possible values. even a simple loop would be doable `$i = 0; while(F($i) <= $search_value) { $i++; }`

Comment: @MikeFonder: it's just math. php is perfectly capable of doing exponentiation via `pow()`, and in v5.6+, it even has the `**` operator.

Comment: @Marc B But this method doesn't much differ from the OP's iteration loop

Comment: yes, but this lets you get arbitrary values. try F(0), then try F(10), F(100) etc.. until you get past whatever the test number is, then back off a bit. For large N (say a few million) this'll be cheaper than having to do a million addition iterations using the "Traditional" method.

Comment: and since it IS just a basic math formula, you can always reverse it and solve for `n` given `F(n)`.

Comment: I think the solution should be easier. Found this as a C++ homework for preliminary course at a college.

Comment: preliminary programming in college usually includes algebra, which is all this is...

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in 1 step:

```
phi = (1+sqrt(5))/2

next = round(current*phi)
```

(Where `round` is a function that returns the closest integer; basically equivalent to `floor(x+0.5)`)

For example, if your current number is `13`: `13 * phi = 21.034441853748632`, which rounds to `21`.

Comment: This works if N is already a Fibonnaci number, but not for e.g. N=4.